# Как объявить статическую переменную?

Tags: kotlin, static

Нужно, чтобы переменная была доступна не только в рамках данного метода, чтобы она была доступна для всех методов и жила вместе с классом.

Comment: Не разбираюсь, но может помочь - https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/430836/

Answer (score 1):

Эквивалент `static` в Java в Котлине это `companion object`.

```
class MyClass { 
  companion object {
    val info = "This is info"    
    fun getMoreInfo():String { return "This is more fun" }
  } 
}

MyClass.info             // This is info
MyClass.getMoreInfo()    // This is more fun
```

Но правильнее использовать глобальные (top level) переменные, если возможно.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-advantage-of-companion-object-vs-static-keyword/4034